# What do GC Pause and GC Cycles mean in JDK Misson Control using ZGC and ShenandoahGC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-mission-control, zgc, shenandoah

When using Serial, Parallel or G1 GCs I can directly see their Collection Counts and accumulated times. However when using ZGC and ShenandoahGC it shows two different Counts and Times for each - for Pause and for Cycles.

Which one of these is the right one for comparing the GC between each other?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare? Note that Java GC algorithms are very complex with lots of nuances. They may not provide comparable metrics in this way.

Comment: I would like to compare the times each GC is active and how often it gets revoked

Comment: Do you mean *invoked*?

Comment: Yes of course! My fault